# Autosar Application Frame vs Nm Frame

Tags: networking, can-bus, autosar

In autosar Network Management/CanNetworkManagement, what is the difference between an Application Frame and an Nm Frame?

I've already searched through the specifications and I've only found one instance of it, I found it in: *AUTOSAR_TPS_SystemTemplate Table 5.32*

> Reference to collection of FrameTriggerings that
>   are used for the wakeup of this PNC (Application
>   Frames or Nm Frames can be used). This
>   reference is optional in case an ecu extract has
>   only indirect pnc access, i.e. ecu is not directly
>   conntected to a network which supports partial
>   network.

I need to know it for Acceptance Testing purposes. I can't seem to differentiate the two by just basing on the specifications. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An Application Frame is just a regular Frame that takes an ISignalIPdu as payload. This is nowhere properly defined but still, that's the gist of it.

Comment: So I assume, 1 way to differentiate the two is that the Nm Frame has a different data format than a regular frame? How can I distinguish the two?

Comment: Yes, the format is different. Plus the modeling of the Pdus hosted by the Frame is different. No offense, but if you really need to write acceptance tests you should not rely on shallow answers on Stack Overflow. You need to go deep, maybe take a training.

Comment: yes, I understand that, but right now, we don't have enough resources for that and I'm just a developer assigned for the task, so I'm not really INTO it. although, do you have any suggestions, because I think, resources for learning autosar are very little in amount.

Comment: True, your best option is to hire a coach for a day or so or attend a class offered by companies that are active in this business.

Answer (score 0):

> what is the difference between an Application Frame and an Nm Frame?

**Application Frame** : It is an generic CAN frame which follows the format
SOF, ID, RTR, IDE, ACK, DATA, CRC, ACKDELI, CRCDELI, EOF, IFS(If applicable)

**Network Managment** : It is sent before application frame to different node to wake-up the node.
It usually has Bus Load Reduction Mechanism and Partial Network Mode.
An NM frame is sent before application frame to wake the node.